# Generated arbitrary functions for wj

Tags: kdb

In the KDB `wj` function:

```
wj[w;c;t;(q;(f0;c0);(f1;c1))]
```

I would like to have an arbitrary number of aggregation functions.

```
myList: `A`B`C..... (can be arbitrary)
```

I would like to generate a list of `sum` functions

```
mySumFuncs: {(sum;x)} each myList
```

and use it this way:

```
wj[w;c;t;(q,mySumFuncs)]
```

But it complains of `type` error.
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

last argument isn't in the correct format try

`wj[w;c;t;enlist[q],mySumFuncs]`

This because the final argument of the wj expects a format of (table;agg1;agg2;...;aggn).
Since a table is a list of dictionaries without the enlist the aggregations are amended to the list of dictionaries rather than a list where the table is the first item.

Easier to see, below is based off the wj example in http://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/#wj-wj1-window-join

```
q)w:-2 1+\:t.time
q)t:([]sym:3#`ibm;time:10:01:01 10:01:04 10:01:08;price:100 101 105)
q)q:([]sym:9#`ibm;time:10:01:01+til 9;ask:101 103 103 104 104 107 108 107 108;bid:98 99 102 103 103 104 106 106 107)
q)f:`sym`time
q)w:-2 1+\:t.time
q)q)wj[w;f;t;(q;(max;`ask);(min;`bid))]
sym time     price ask bid
--------------------------
ibm 10:01:01 100   103 98
ibm 10:01:04 101   104 99
ibm 10:01:08 105   108 104
q)(q;(max;`ask);(min;`bid))
+`sym`time`ask`bid!(`ibm`ibm`ibm`ibm`ibm`ibm`ibm`ibm`ibm;10:01:01 10:01:02 10..
(max;`ask)
(min;`bid)
q)q,((max;`ask);(min;`bid))
`sym`time`ask`bid!(`ibm;10:01:01;101;98)
`sym`time`ask`bid!(`ibm;10:01:02;103;99)
`sym`time`ask`bid!(`ibm;10:01:03;103;102)
`sym`time`ask`bid!(`ibm;10:01:04;104;103)
`sym`time`ask`bid!(`ibm;10:01:05;104;103)
`sym`time`ask`bid!(`ibm;10:01:06;107;104)
`sym`time`ask`bid!(`ibm;10:01:07;108;106)
`sym`time`ask`bid!(`ibm;10:01:08;107;106)
`sym`time`ask`bid!(`ibm;10:01:09;108;107)
(max;`ask)
(min;`bid)
q)enlist[q],((max;`ask);(min;`bid))
+`sym`time`ask`bid!(`ibm`ibm`ibm`ibm`ibm`ibm`ibm`ibm`ibm;10:01:01 10:01:02 10..
(max;`ask)
(min;`bid)
```

Comment: Hi sir,  why do we need to enlist q? And is there a difference between "enlist q" and "enlist[q]"?

Comment: Hey @delita edited my answer to provide a proper explanation. Hope it's a bit clearer